# react leaflet map not rendering properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, leaflet, next.js13

[image]

Using leaflet seems like I have  so issues with marker to correctly render.
Otherwise map render correctly

```
export default function Map({
  zoomActive = false,
  zoom = 13,
  position,
  marker = null,
  popout = null,
}: MapProps) {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={position}
      scrollWheelZoom={zoomActive}
      zoom={zoom}
      className="relative h-[400px] w-full"
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {marker && (
        <Marker position={marker}>
          <Popup>{popout}</Popup>
        </Marker>
      )}
    </MapContainer>
  );
```

this is my map component.

```
export function MapWrapper({ ...props }: MapProps) {
  const [Map, setMap] = useState<MapComponentType>();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        const dynamicallyImportedMap = (await import("./map")).default;
        setMap(() => dynamicallyImportedMap);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  if (typeof window === "undefined" || !Map) {
    return null;
  }

  return <Map {...props} />;
}
```

and thats my map wrapper.

using NEXTjs 13. The position is correct and I do have :

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

included in my file.

just want standard Pin, or any fix that will allow me show some decent marker.